# Running more then one Else If statement on a page PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I was wondering what the best way to run two(or more) else if statements on one PHP page. This is part of a form where its looking for a ticket type and how many days. I need to run two of these statement on one page and I doesn't seem to work because once it hit a true statement it stops. How can I get this to work?

```
<?php
    if($ticket_type=='Child (5 & Under)'){
     echo "
     <select name=\"ticket_type[]\">
       <option value=\"\">Select one...</option>
       <option selected=\"selected\">Child (5 &amp; Under)</option>
       <option>Child (6 - 12)</option>
       <option>Teen (13 - 17)</option>
     </select>";
    }else if($ticket_type=='Child (6 - 12)'){
     echo "
     <select name=\"ticket_type[]\">
       <option value=\"\">Select one...</option>
       <option>Child (5 &amp; Under)</option>
       <option selected=\"selected\">Child (6 - 12)</option>
       <option>Teen (13 - 17)</option>
     </select>";
    }else if($ticket_type=='Teen (13 - 17)'){
     echo "
     <select name=\"ticket_type[]\">
       <option value=\"\">Select one...</option>
       <option>Child (5 &amp; Under)</option>
       <option>Child (6 - 12)</option>
       <option selected=\"selected\">Teen (13 - 17)</option>
     </select>";
    }else{
     echo "
     <select name=\"ticket_type[]\">
       <option value=\"\">Select one...</option>
       <option>Child (5 &amp; Under)</option>
       <option>Child (6 - 12)</option>
       <option>Teen (13 - 17)</option>
     </select>";


  }?>




<?php
        if($days=='1 Day'){
         echo "
         <select name=\"ticket_type[]\">
           <option value="">Select one...</option>
           <option selected=\"selected\">1 Day</option>
           <option>2 Days</option>
           <option>3 out of 4 Days</option>
         </select>";
        }else if($days=='2 Days'){
         echo "
         <select name=\"ticket_type[]\">
           <option value="">Select one...</option>
           <option>1 Day</option>
           <option selected=\"selected\">2 Days</option>
           <option>3 out of 4 Days</option>
         </select>";
        }else if($days=='3 out of 4 Days'){
         echo "
         <select name=\"ticket_type[]\">
           <option value="">Select one...</option>
           <option>1 Day</option>
           <option>2 Days</option>
           <option selected=\"selected\">3 out of 4 Days</option>
         </select>";
        }else{
         echo "
         <select name=\"days[]\">
           <option value="">Select one...</option>
           <option>1 Day</option>
           <option>2 Days</option>
           <option>3 out of 4 Days</option>
         </select>";
        }?>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you saying the second `if` block is not running?

Comment: You can print raw HTML by closing the PHP tag with `?>`, pasting in your HTML, and opening up PHP again with `<?php`.

Comment: Next to if, there are loops / foreach'es in PHP. With your <select> example, I think it's worth you learn about them: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php - and learn about arrays. This will prevent you copying the same text over and over again to only change a fraction. Best rule: Don't repeat yourself.

Comment: I disagree, this looks like it will print two <select> elements.  The script doesn't *stop* once it hits a true condition, it just skips that else if block and continues past it.  What output do you get when you run this script?

Comment: Indeed can you edit to include your current output and desired output. On the topic of @hakre s comment. I'd suggest a DRY (Don't repeat yourself) approach where each option has a `<?php if($ticket_type == 'Teen (13 - 17)') echo 'selected="selected"';?>` statement in it

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify the code immensely:

```
$options = array(
   'Select One' => 'Select One',
   '1 Day' => '1 Day',
   '2 Days' => '2 Days',
   '3 or more' => '3 or More'
);

echo '<select name="ticket_type[]">';
foreach($options as $key => $val) {
   $select = (($key == $days) ? ' selected="selected"' : '');
   echo "<option value=\"", htmlspecialchars($key), "\"$select>", htmlspecialchars($val), "</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

This way, you have only ONE place where the select options are specified, so if you need to add more in the future, you only change that one place. Right now you'd have to change every single section of your if() block, which'll get tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

oh boy... why you make things so complicated ?

```
<select name="ticket_type[]">
   <option value="">Select one...</option>
   <option <? echo ($ticket_type == 'Child (5 &amp; Under) ? 'selected="selected" : ''; ?>'>Child (5 &amp; Under)</option>
   <option <? echo ($ticket_type == 'Child (6 - 12) ? 'selected="selected" : ''; ?>>Child (6 - 12)</option>
   <option <? echo ($ticket_type == 'Child (13 - 17) ? 'selected="selected" : ''; ?>>Teen (13 - 17)</option>
</select>";
```

but you really should consider using ID's so you dont have to compare strings.

Comment: This *could* be further improved but shows a very good point as it is, +1

Comment: of course it can, it was only intended to show hot to get rid of all this redundancy.

Comment: And that is one important step of the way, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, that's kind of messy. You should read up on [PHP's Alternative Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

```
<?php if ($condition): ?>
This is a test..
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Just remember with colon syntax you must use `elseif` and not `else if` (in case OP was unaware)

Comment: This is acually the same as the OP has a problem with (compare with the [switch suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668341/running-more-then-one-else-if-statement-on-a-page-php/7668376#7668376) if you can see deleted posts), using a "fancy* feature does not make it better nor easier to understand.